# sqlite 3.7.17 compilation error under FreeBSD

Tags: sqlite, gcc, freebsd

Many users at StackOverflow advised me to migrate to SQlite, so, I am trying to, but cannot, compile sqlite3 source under FreeBSD.  The following error occurs:

`sqlite3.c:23527: error: 'fchmod' undeclared here (not in a function)`

System:

`FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE`
`gcc 4.2.1`

Can anyone offer advice or suggestions?

P.S. I cannot update the system as it is a working server.

Comment: Well, the most recent version of SQLite to date maintained by the FreeBSD community is 3.7.14.1. So why bother compiling it manually if it is available via [ports and packages](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports.html)? Manual compilation is generally discouraged in FreeBSD because you have to manually resolve the dependencies.

Comment: @YasirArsanukaev I want to have my program with compiled into it SQLite. 1) Its simple to setup, deploy and maintain such compilation on other machines 2) do not depend on the system, only need to compile sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man fchmod` shows:

```
NAME
     chmod, fchmod, lchmod — change mode of file

LIBRARY
     Standard C Library (libc, -lc)

SYNOPSIS
     #include <sys/stat.h>
```

So you need to add `#include <sys/stat.h>` to the top of the failing file (`sqlite3.c`) at least.  There may be a better header file to include it from.  You may even find that it is already there but fenced out by an `#ifdef`.

Answer (score 1):

Yasir is right in that you should be using the ports of all of the already-ported software you need. If you aren't administrating the server yourself, you ought to be able to ask the admin(s) to install the databases/sqlite3 port for you.

Back to your actual question, it is difficult to know, why the fchmod is not declared in your case -- it is declared in `<sys/stat.h>`. Perhaps, you are using Makefile generated on one platform (Linux?) to build sqlite on a different platform (FreeBSD)? You should not do that -- configure needs to run locally.

But, again, do not build it yourself...

Answer (score 0):

After resolving this same build error (different line number) for `sqlite3 3.33.0` on `SCO OpenServer 5.0.7`, the code fragment involved for the a fix is near a comment that mentions `fchmod() on OpenBSD`.  Presuming that `FreeBSD` might be similar to `OpenBSD`, perhaps the fix for this issue could have been because `_XOPEN_SOURCE` was not defined.

```
/*
** We need to define _XOPEN_SOURCE as follows in order to enable
** recursive mutexes on most Unix systems and fchmod() on OpenBSD.
** But _XOPEN_SOURCE define causes problems for Mac OS X, so omit
** it.
*/
#if !defined(_XOPEN_SOURCE) && !defined(__DARWIN__) && !defined(__APPLE__)
#  define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#endif
```

In the amalgamation sources, the code is in `sqliteInt.h`, between

```
/************** End of sqliteLimit.h *****************************************/
/************** Continuing where we left off in sqliteInt.h ******************/
```

and

```
/************** Include hash.h in the middle of sqliteInt.h ******************/
/************** Begin file hash.h ********************************************/
```

The suggestions to use the `OpenBSD` sources are valid, because those sources would have been patched to resolve platform-specific build issues.  This answer provides a potential link to a possible root cause since this Q/A came up in a search involving resolving an error message almost identical to the one in the question.

In the `SCO OpenServer 5.0.7` case, unrelated to this question, but since it is mentioned in this answer, and as it may come up in other's search results, the problem in my case was the reverse situation, where `_XOPEN_SOURCE` caused the error and required a patch like:

```
$ diff -u sqlite3.c.orig sqlite3.c
--- sqlite3.c.orig      2020-08-14 08:42:52.000000000 -0500
+++ sqlite3.c   2020-10-25 13:38:01.000000000 -0500
@@ -13633,10 +13633,11 @@
 /*
 ** We need to define _XOPEN_SOURCE as follows in order to enable
 ** recursive mutexes on most Unix systems and fchmod() on OpenBSD.
-** But _XOPEN_SOURCE define causes problems for Mac OS X, so omit
-** it.
+** But _XOPEN_SOURCE define causes problems for Mac OS X, and for
+** SCO OpenServer 5.0.7, so omit it.
 */
-#if !defined(_XOPEN_SOURCE) && !defined(__DARWIN__) && !defined(__APPLE__)
+#if !defined(_XOPEN_SOURCE) && !defined(__DARWIN__) && !defined(__APPLE__) \
+ && !defined(_SCO_DS)
 #  define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
 #endif
```

EDIT: It is quite possible that the suggestion to `#include <sys/stat.h>` was the best fix at the time for this version of `sqlite`.  A detailed search on the error message looking for activity in the original time frame of this question, reveals a number of other users having the same problem and being given the same advice, namely, to incorporate the include statement higher up in the `sqlite3.c` amalgamation file.